# Converting normal/on-demand instance to Spot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is the method of converting an on-demand instance to a spot instance? Do I need to make an image first or is there a setting/option I'm missing?

Is there a notification prior to terminating a spot instance when your bid threshold is reached, e.g., a few minutes?

I'm using EC2 just for personal/hobbyist stuff, so nothing mission critical on data integrity, backup, availability, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No setting/option. You indeed must make an image from your on-demand instance first. Then you can start any new instance with this image. (These are only 3 or four clicks in the AWS mgmt. console anyway).